# Split every character from string in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a list and I need to split every string into individual characters.

```
mylist = ['TCTAGTCCAGATAATCTGGT', 'GTGTTGGTACTGTAATGAAA', 'AGTTCTCTGGATCCTTCGGA', 'GGAATTGACGTCCCCAGGAA', 'GTCGTTGTCGTTCAGGAGTT', 'GGAGTCCGTCAGAAGAGGTC', 'GATTCCGATCAGATGAAGAA', 'CTTTCTATCGGGAAGAGGAG', 'ATGTCTTGAGATCGGGTCGT', 'ATTAAGATCCTCCATGATTC', 'ATCGTCGAAAGTAGTGGGAA']
```

And I need

```
output = ['T', 'C', 'T', ... 'A', 'A']
```

If tried so many ways and can't figure it out.

Comment: should the split chars still remain in their groups?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Yes, if possible. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use embedded list comprehension for this.

```
mylist = ['TCTAGTCCAGATAATCTGGT', 'GTGTTGGTACTGTAATGAAA', 'AGTTCTCTGGATCCTTCGGA', 'GGAATTGACGTCCCCAGGAA', 'GTCGTTGTCGTTCAGGAGTT', 'GGAGTCCGTCAGAAGAGGTC', 'GATTCCGATCAGATGAAGAA', 'CTTTCTATCGGGAAGAGGAG', 'ATGTCTTGAGATCGGGTCGT', 'ATTAAGATCCTCCATGATTC', 'ATCGTCGAAAGTAGTGGGAA']

chars = [c for s in mylist for c in s]
print(chars)
# ['T', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'G', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'G', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'T', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'A']
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to python and list comprehension is not coming easily to me.

Comment: Note that the current accepted answer is different from the example that you gave. You gave example output of a list of string whereas the accepted answer returns a list of lists of strings.

Comment: @BramVanroy I agree, your output is like the output in the question. I only posted my answer cause in the quetion comments i asked the OP if they wanted the split chars to remain in their groups and they said yes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a list comprehension to create new sub lists where each char is split.

```py
mylist = ['TCTAGTCCAGATAATCTGGT', 'GTGTTGGTACTGTAATGAAA', 'AGTTCTCTGGATCCTTCGGA', 'GGAATTGACGTCCCCAGGAA', 'GTCGTTGTCGTTCAGGAGTT', 'GGAGTCCGTCAGAAGAGGTC', 'GATTCCGATCAGATGAAGAA', 'CTTTCTATCGGGAAGAGGAG', 'ATGTCTTGAGATCGGGTCGT', 'ATTAAGATCCTCCATGATTC', 'ATCGTCGAAAGTAGTGGGAA']
my_split_list = [[char for char in element] for element in mylist]
print(mylist)
print(my_split_list)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['TCTAGTCCAGATAATCTGGT', 'GTGTTGGTACTGTAATGAAA', 'AGTTCTCTGGATCCTTCGGA', 'GGAATTGACGTCCCCAGGAA', 'GTCGTTGTCGTTCAGGAGTT', 'GGAGTCCGTCAGAAGAGGTC', 'GATTCCGATCAGATGAAGAA', 'CTTTCTATCGGGAAGAGGAG', 'ATGTCTTGAGATCGGGTCGT', 'ATTAAGATCCTCCATGATTC', 'ATCGTCGAAAGTAGTGGGAA']
[['T', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'G', 'G', 'T'], ['G', 'T', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'G', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'T', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'A'], ['A', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'A'], ['G', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'A'], ['G', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'T'], ['G', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'T', 'C'], ['G', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'A'], ['C', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'G'], ['A', 'T', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'T'], ['A', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'C'], ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'A']]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need.